# Flutter file picker to store multiple files to Firebase Storage at once

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-storage

So i know there is an example available on pub.dev for multiple files method for file picker such as below.

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true);

if (result != null) {
  List<File> files = result.paths.map((path) => File(path)).toList();
} else {
  // User canceled the picker
}
```

What i would like to ask for help is how can i get the files for this allow multiple method and store it into my firebase storage ? I am able to storage and retrieve files with the single method but for multiple files i just cant find the correct way because i would like the user to be able to directly select all the desired files and upload to storage at once. Please help.

How can i continue from the above example ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload multiple files to Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673499/how-to-upload-multiple-files-to-firebase)

Comment: Nope sir. That does not help me .